# Get Kubuntu 18.04.3 multi-monitor support to launch apps in primary screen?

Tags: kubuntu, multiple-monitors

Setting up a 2nd display(HDMI output) on a laptop(Lenovo z70) with NVidia card/drivers( Kubuntu 18.04.3 ) and in the Display settings I setup the 2nd monitor to be above the laptop/Primary display(attached above in Display settings dialog).

But when I start a new application, they start on the 2nd screen.  Only if I setup my screen layout so my laptop(Primary) screen is to the left of the 2nd screen does it function with apps starting on the primary screen.

Running rxandr didn't change anything:
PRIMARY="eDP-1-1"
SECONDARY="HDMI-1-1"
xrandr --output ${PRIMARY} --primary --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal \
       --output ${SECONDARY} --mode 1920x1080 --above ${PRIMARY} \
       --output DP-1-1 --off \
       --output HDMI-1-2 --off

The ONLY way I've found to get this to work mostly as 'expected' is to right click on an app's Title bar, More Actions -> Special Window Settings -> Initial Placement - Force - Under Mouse

So why does the "primary" screen setting work only when it is to the left of the other screen(s) and is there a way to get this to work besides forcing through multiple menu levels off an app title bar?